# jQuery .validate rules don't appear to be applying? (jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

http://jsfiddle.net/sK9tL/1/

When I manually add the rule()'s in the console on my form page, it appears to validate as expected.

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the way I am formatting this?

```
$('#freeFormAdd').validate({
        rules:{
            freeFormName: {
                required: true, 
            },
            freeFormPrice: {
                required: true, 
            },
            freeFormQty: {
                required: true, 
            }
        }
    });
```

Then I use the .valid() to determine if the form is ready to submit. Since the page is "seamless" I don't need the form to submit, just to add some items to a cart (which is commented out in the jsfiddle).

Any advice?

Comment: Please include enough code to duplicate the issue.  Without looking at your jsFiddle, this question is impossible to answer.  It's always ok to include a demo link but questions must be fully "self-contained" and not rely on external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form elements should have `name` attribute not `id` attribute, validator selects the elements based on their `name` attributes. Also instead of listening to the click event, you can use the `submitHandler` method:

```
 $('#freeFormAdd').validate({
     rules: {
         freeFormName: {
             required: true,
         },
         freeFormPrice: {
             required: true,
         },
         freeFormQty: {
             required: true,
         }
     },
     submitHandler: function () {
         alert('the form is valid');
     }
 });
```

Please note that I have moved the button to the `form` element's context so it triggers the submit event.

http://jsfiddle.net/QU3XM/

Comment: WOW. I feel like a total tard now. I'll play with the SubmitHandler for sure, but right now the validation was an afterthought to a more elaborate amount of code that is called when that button is pressed. Adding the `name` instead of just `id` fixed it.